# MySQL Cluster 7.4.15 - Ndb_Restore Fail Because an Orphan Fragment

Tags: mysql, database, fragment, cluster-computing

i want to know if it's possible to drop a table fragment that is not letting me perform a restore with the NDB_RESTORE tool.

When i run the restore, it throws the following error:

*Create table `db_died_maestro/def/NDB$FKM_3194_0_mae_tipo_reg_evaluacion` failed: 721: Schema object with given name already exists
Restore: Failed to restore table: `db_died_maestro/def/NDB$FKM_3194_0_mae_tipo_reg_evaluacion` ... Exiting
NDBT_ProgramExit: 1 - Failed*

I have already drop the DB_DIED_MAESTRO database previous to run the restore, but this fragment is not being dropped along with the database.

I have check that the fragment is in the database catalog using this querys:

*select * from ndbinfo.operations_per_fragment 
where fq_name like 'db_died_maestro%'*

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehlds.png)

And this query:

*select * from ndbinfo.memory_per_fragment
where fq_name like '%FKM_3194_0_mae_tipo_reg_evaluacion'*

[query 2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uhOR.png)

This fragment was created on a previous run of the NDB_RESTORE tool. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The table is a foreign key 'mock' table (indicated by the name NDB$FKM prefix).

Foreign key mock tables are created transiently in some cases to implement the foreign_key_checks = 0 feature of MySQL.  This feature requires storage engines to support unordered creation of tables with partially defined foreign key constraints which can be abritrarily enabled (without revalidation) at a later time.

Foreign key mock tables are normally entirely managed by the Ndb storage engine component of MySQL, and so should not be visible unless there has been a failure or bug of some kind.

If you can share information about activities occurring before this problem then that would help us understand how this happened and whether it can be avoided.

As a workaround it should be possible for you to use the ndb_drop_table utility to drop this table, before re-attempting the failing restore.  You may have to escape the $ in the name passed as a command line argument from a shell.  Probably you should check for any other NDB$FKM tables in a similar situation.

Comment: This is a new cluster installation, when i run the NDB_RESTORE tool the first time it fails because the number of tables exceed the MaxNoOfTables parameter in the configuration file of the cluster. So, i have to change the parameter in the configuration file, restart the cluster, drop the all databases created by the failed restore and try it again, but then i was getting the error explained in my question. As a workaround i have already recreate the Data Nodes with the "ndbd --initial" option and it works but i would like to know now if i could fix it with doing this workaround.